# delete one row by Specific ID which the same is not present another table Column ID

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select *from add_member;
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-------------------+
| member_ID | member_name | member_phone | member_department |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     12345 | kishore     | 89482934     | IT738             |
|     12347 | ram         | 783892389    | IT721829          |
|    12346 | vardhan     | 902112       | TI5738            |

mysql> select *from ownbook;


    +--------+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------

    | BookID | Bookname | member_ID | member_name | from       | to         |
    +--------+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
    |   1006 | physics  |     12346 | ram         | 2016-07-05 | 2016-07-20 |
    +--------+----------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i want to able to delete data which is ID-12345,12347 but when i try to delete 12346 it sholud not be delete becoz it is in another table

Comment: I think you have foreign key kinking both tables. Delete before from ownbook record with that ID

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
delete from add_member where member_ID  not exists(select member_ID from ownbook)
```

or you can use NOT IN like

```
delete from add_member where member_ID  not in(select member_ID from ownbook)
```

If it is specific data then simply do:

```
delete from add_member 
where member_ID  not in(select member_ID from ownbook where member_id in(12345,12347))
```

Comment: but i want to delete specific data either 2345 or 2347 but not 2346 becoz it is in another table

Comment: it is delete two data...i want delete one data

Comment: i want delete 12345  ID only

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete one specific id if and only if it shouldn't be there in second table then you can do this:

`delete from add_member where member_ID='SEPCIFIC_ID_YOU_WANT' and member_ID not in(select member_ID from ownbook)`

Working 100% tested.